# How to get the result set's intersection?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Result set1:

```
select code from quote where cond1
```

Result set2:

```
select code from vix  where cond2
```

I want a set containing `code` which is the intersection of `Result set1` and `Result set2`.

```
select code from quote where cond1 and code in (select code from vix  where cond2);
```

It can't work!Same error info for both GMB and Akina 's answer.

RROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Let's display the table structure:

```
show create table quote;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| quote | CREATE TABLE `quote` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17173979 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

show create table vix;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                  |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| vix   | CREATE TABLE `vix` (
  `code` text,
  `span` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vix` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `extrem_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

Search code set from table `quote` and `vix`.

```
select code from quote where volume > 10000000 and date='2020-08-24';
+-------+
| code  |
+-------+
| zom   |
| ibio  |
```

Note : about 120 rows.

```
select code from vix  where span >30;
+---------+
| code    |
+---------+
| canf    |
| ensv    |
```

Note : about 1100 rows.
Get the intersection of the two result set:

```
MariaDB [stock]> select code 
    -> from quote q 
    -> where 
    ->     volume > 10000000 and date='2020-08-24'
    ->     and exists (select 1 from vix v where span >30 and (v.code = q.code));
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Would be easy using INTERSECT if MySQL supported all set operators. What if intersecting NULLs exist or multiple rows with the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your (pseudo) query query should do what you want. I find, however, that using `exists` is more efficient when the list of values gets bigger. I would phrase this as:

```
select code 
from quote q 
where 
    cond1
    and exists (select 1 from vix v where cond2 and v.code = q.code)
```

Comment: New issue arise,please watch my latest post.

Comment: @scrapy: your tables have different collations. You can do: `v.code collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci = q.code`.

Comment: I get it ,succed. what does `select 1` mean here?

Comment: @scrapy: `exists` just checks if *some row* exists that satisfy the condition, the actual results of the subquery are discarded. `select 1` is a convention to represent that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code 
FROM (select code from quote where cond1) q1
JOIN (select code from vix   where cond2) q2 USING (code)
```

Comment: @scrapy Collation coercibility problem is not related to the query itself.

Comment: RROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @scrapy *Every derived table must have its own alias* Provided SQL code cannot result in this error message.  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae5c3d71829ccecf0f5e39d5172b11f6). You just made a typo or error somewhere when adapting the query to your structures.

Comment: Sorry,checked again,it is my typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
select code 
from quote q 
where 
    cond1
    and exists (select 1 from vix v where cond2 and (v.code collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci = q.code))
```